# Problem when using gas discharge tubes in surge protection circuit

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, surge-protection

I am working on a surge protection circuit. My schematic is shown below.

In this design, I used 3 poles GDT 350V DC spark ([this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/2026-35-C2LF/1220301?s=N4IgTCBcDa4AxgGwFoDMBWZBhMAZAYiALoC%2BQA)) over at the beginning, followed by some varistors (V1, V2, V3, V4.)

Every time I plug in my circuit to a 220V/50Hz AC source my fuses immediately blow up.

I used an oscilloscope to catch the pulse,  and I saw a 400V spike appear at the time I plug in the AC source. That spike tripped the gas discharge tube and so blew my fuse.

When I removed the GDT, everything worked fine. My fuses no longer blow up and I could not catch any spike larger than 330V.

Does the problem come from the GDT?

[image]

Comment: 220vac has 325V peak, so all your elements seems to be rated too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparison you can [see](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/gas_discharge_tubes/littelfuse_gdt_ac_cg3_datasheet.pdf.pdf) that a GDT for 240VAC mains has a rated DC breakdown voltage of 600VDC, compared to your's 350VDC. The same also applies to all of your varistors, they should have a breakdown voltage somewhere around 450VDC.

The MOV is slower response compared to the GDT, so the GDT strikes first. But after the spike has left, the GDT will still conduct the mains until the mains drops to near zero volts - each zero cross of 50/60Hz mains. Therefore it may not withstand  such energy dump if mounted alone, the MOV which is slower at the time starts conducting and unloads the GDT. The breakdown voltages have to be: MOV lower, GDT higher.

Answer (score 0):

At 400V input a 350V GDT would turn on and short out the fuses. If I remember right the GDT should be at a much higher voltage (check the regulatory requirements for your product like IEC61010)